# Why did the party scene in Precious cut suddenly to a black screen for several seconds then skip to the next scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, precious

In Precious (2009), in the party scene, Precious was enjoying the party, when male nurse John met her. He asked her about the trophy she was holding, and he gave her some post card type thing. She took the card and took John to the "*Day care woman*" character. Now *Day Care Woman* was **shocked** by seeing both.

Suddenly, the scene was skipped, with 4 seconds of a black screen before the next scene.

Why was this scene in Precious skipped in this way?

Comment: Dear fellow users, please don't downvote and closevote perfectly good questions for minor grammar mistakes. There's no rule that says askers must be native English speakers and it was perfectly clear what they were trying to say

Answer (score 2):

From the talk between John and Precious, we can understand that he was interested in dating either ms.Rain or her friend Catherine. Precious seems sceptical about it and then she decides to introduce him to the "Daycare woman" character as a more suitable -according to her- match for him. I think this was just a funny moment - especially after the look that the daycare woman gave him - and I do not think that there was much more to it than that.

This scene, however, had a dreamlike feel (like the other of Precious' dreams) - so maybe this was only what she was imagining; John and the daycare woman ending up together. In that case, the black screen would serve as a transition to the next scene (reality). However, this is only my opinion and there might be a better explanation to the scene and the black screen.